# D3 alignment of gridline for x and y axis

Tags: d3.js

I am currently facing problem in setting grid line for a graph.

**Problem**

i) x grid line is not aligned to the x-axis

ii)y grid line is not appearing.

```
The code and output are in the
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QyX6pajTEFWnLz3FWQzb?p=preview)

Anyone can guide me on this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*i) x grid line is not aligned to the x-axis*

**Reason:**

You are doing like this

```
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
```

It should have been like this:

```
.attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left + "," + (height+ margin.top) + ")")
```

So you missed the margin left and margin top given to the graph, please add them as shown above.

*ii)y grid line is not appearing.*

**Reason:**

```
  svg.append("g")     
      .attr("class", "grid")
      .call(ygridlines <--- this is a function
          .tickSize(-width)
          .tickFormat("")
      )
```

it should have been

```
svg.append("g")     
      .attr("class", "grid")
      .attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left + "," + (margin.top) + ")")
      .call(ygridlines()
          .tickSize(-width)
          .tickFormat("")
      )
```

Also you missed the transform for the y axis.

Working code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/VhEdn9NgJQG9gGmG3oys?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for your guidance! i will continue trying on d3js =)